# error when moving a file uploaded with multer: resource busy or locked

Tags: node.js, express, filepath, multer

I have a node+express app that receives files and uploads them to a folder, for which I use multer.

In it's current form, my server.js has:

```
var multer = require('multer');
app.use(multer({ dest: './uploads/' }).single('files'));
```

which sends all files to the /uploads directory, with a randomly generated name to avoid conflicts.

That all works fine, however, I need to modify it so that it creates a folder with the randomly generated name and places the file inside (so if a file is randomly named "`asdf`", then it should end up as `uploads/asdf/asdf`.

Since the node way of moving files is using fs.rename, I included the following code in my upload route:

```
fs.rename('uploads/' + newFile.uploadname, 'uploads/' + newFile.uploadname + '/' + newFile.uploadname, function(err) {
  if (err) throw err
  console.log('Successfully renamed - AKA moved!')
})
```

(newFile.uploadname should be, and actually is, the name generated by multer).

When that code executes, I get this output:

```
D:\NodeApp\app\routes\private\upload.js:35                                                                           
      if (err) throw err                                                                                             
               ^                                                                                                     



Error: EBUSY: resource busy or locked, rename 'D:\NodeApp\uploads\b9998bcbb10326c05f305a6a5a0adb9a' -> 'D:\NodeApp\up
loads\b9998bcbb10326c05f305a6a5a0adb9a\b9998bcbb10326c05f305a6a5a0adb9a'                                             
    at Error (native)
```

The file is uploaded properly but not moved, nor the directory created.

What is happening?

Comment: can you log  `uploads/' + newFile.uploadname` maybe the path is not trusted

Comment: @farhadamjady nevermind, I'm an idiot. See the answer I posted for more details.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I was trying to move a file named 'asdf' to a folder called also 'asdf'... Obviously (in restrospect) that folder can't be created because the name is already being used by the file that will be copied. Moving the file to a temporal folder first and then creating the folder solved the issue.